# boost regex pattern syntax confusion

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost

I am using boost regex, but I am confused about the syntax used by boost regex. If I want to use pattern "bb" to match the string "aabbcc", I have to make the pattern "bb" to ".*bb.*" so that the string would be matched. This is wired because in perl you don't need to add ".*" at the front and the end of "bb". Did I miss something about boost regex or this is just the flavor of boost regex? Below are my simple source code for this question:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    boost::regex regex_bb01("bb");
    boost::regex regex_bb02(".*bb");
    boost::regex regex_bb03("bb.*");
    boost::regex regex_bb04(".*bb.*");

    if(boost::regex_match("aabbcc", regex_bb01))
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb01 is matched\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb01 is Not matched\n";
    if(boost::regex_match("aabbcc", regex_bb02))
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb02 is matched\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb02 is Not matched\n";
    if(boost::regex_match("aabbcc", regex_bb03))
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb03 is matched\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb03 is Not matched\n";
    if(boost::regex_match("aabbcc", regex_bb04))
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb04 is matched\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"the regex_bb04 is Not matched\n";
}
```

the result looks like this:

[root@localhost BoostCase]# ./regex_test

the regex_bb01 is Not matched

the regex_bb02 is Not matched

the regex_bb03 is Not matched

the regex_bb04 is matched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From boost documentation the function regex_match

> The algorithm regex_match determines whether a given regular expression matches **all** of a given character sequence denoted by a pair of bidirectional-iterators, the algorithm is defined as follows, the main use of this function is data input validation.

In case you want to use 'bb' to match, you will need to use boost::regex_search instead

Comment: Python makes the same distinction between *match* and *search*. Unless you're validating a string (generally you can trust your input because it is machine-generated) it is a *search* that you want. It is easy enough to add start and end of line anchors `^` and `$` if you need to verify the whole string